# URLSession not returning anything

Tags: ios, swift, urlsession

This is the code :

```
let url = URL(string: requestUrl)
var request = URLRequest(url: url!, cachePolicy: .reloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData, timeoutInterval: 60)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
if bodyDict != nil && type(of: bodyDict) != NSNull.self {
    var jsonString: String? = nil
    if let anError = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: bodyDict ?? [String: Any](), options: .prettyPrinted) {
        jsonString = String(data: anError, encoding: .utf8)
    }

    if jsonString != nil {
        print("bodyDict : \(bodyDict)")
        request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: bodyDict ?? [String: Any]())
    }
}

let session = URLSession.shared
let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
    if error != nil {
        print("APIClient failed to get InApp Messages: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "" )")
    } else {
        var responseString = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)
        var responseDict: [AnyHashable : Any]? = nil
        if let anEncoding = responseString?.data(using: String.Encoding(rawValue: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)) {
            responseDict = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: anEncoding, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String : Any]
            print("sessionId responseDict : \(responseDict)")
        }

        if responseDict == nil {
            responseString = "{\"error\":\"\(responseString ?? "")\"}"
            print("sessionId error : \(responseString)")
            if let anEncoding = responseString?.data(using: String.Encoding(rawValue: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)) {
                responseDict = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: anEncoding, options: .mutableContainers) as? [AnyHashable : Any]
            }
        }
    }
})

dataTask.resume()
```

But dataTask never returns anything, not even error. Same request on postman works fine. **bodyDict** :

> ["latitude": "76.69", "event_name": "nitishtest", "cart_id": "60",
>   "platform": "1", "auth_token":
>   "1aae7a2afa86b0f0ede377ca29c5a503b837054f", "session_id": "12",
>   "push_device_id": "522", "longitude": "0", "campaign_id": "1967",
>   "brand": "nike"]

Comment: It should work perfectly fine

Comment: @Satish : My thought too. But it is not :(

Comment: Try setting a timeout, maybe it's just taking a _really_ long time? Also, use Alamofire or something, don't do raw HTTP calls like this, you could save yourself a lot of headaches.

Comment: @GuyKogus : Will try the timeout. But can't use Amalofire. Can't use any library.

Comment: `Same request on postman works fine.`. No, it's clear that there aren't same. You can print everything and compare step by step.

Comment: Also you can double check your `auth_token` key. Maybe it should be on the header and not on the body data.

Comment: @Desdenova : Ya, already checked that. It goes in the params

Comment: @GuyKogus : Increasing timeout didn't work either.

Comment: @Nitish print everything and compare, you are clearly missing something.

Comment: @Desdenova : There is nothing else left to print. bodyDict is the only thing. I have compared the runtime url with the one on postman, character by character. They are all same.

Comment: Is the url secure? if not have you enabled arbitrary loads? check your console for errors

Comment: @Scriptable : It is https. And yes, I have allowed arbitrary loads in info.plist

Comment: You can export your postman request into swift code directly from postman, try that and compare the code... see if there are any functional differences

Comment: @Nitish - Copy Swift code from the postman and check and compare with your code.

Comment: @Scriptable : If that is so, it is remarkable. Let me try that.

Comment: @Scriptable : Postman request also not giving any response

Comment: @Scriptable and all others : Here is an interesting fact. I tried running this on simulator. And it worked fine. Issue is coming on device. I tried changing the network but still getting the issue. Internet is however working fine on the device.

Comment: are you connecting to an online api or local machine? got to be a routing issue or something similar

Comment: @Scriptable : Found the solution. I have posted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so I found the fix. For **iOS 11**, I had to set `waitsForConnectivity` for `URLSession`. I was testing on iOS 11.x

So the code is as follows for `URLSession` :

```
let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
configuration.httpCookieStorage = nil
configuration.requestCachePolicy = NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
   configuration.waitsForConnectivity = false
}

let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration)
```

Answer (score -4):

You should not call datatask.resume() separately.

call .resume() function after dataTask closing bracket.

let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in

```
        }.resume()
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with calling `datatask.resume()`. It's the exact same as `.resume()` directly after the `dataTask`.
And stick to the question. This is not a valid answer to solve the issue.